# Calling keyevent from mouse

Tags: javascript

I need to emulate a key press with click on a link. The keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> must be called with a click on a link, or a similar function.

Comment: are you trying to increase/decrease font size when a link is clicked?

Answer (score 3):

You can't invoke key press with JavaScript.

However, you can control zoom level with JavaScript, here is example for IE and Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/cMCuz/2/

Edit: now supports Firefox as well.

Required JavaScript:

```
var _zoomLevel = 100;

function ChangeZoomLevel(diff) {
    _zoomLevel += diff;
    var oDiv = document.getElementById("Contents");
    if (typeof oDiv.style.MozTransform == "string")
        oDiv.style.MozTransform = "scale(" + (_zoomLevel / 100) + ")";
    else if (typeof oDiv.style.zoom == "string")
        oDiv.style.zoom = _zoomLevel  + "%";
}
```

Sample buttons:

```
<button type="button" onclick="ChangeZoomLevel(10);">+</button>
<button type="button" onclick="ChangeZoomLevel(-10);">-</button>
```

This will change the zoom level of whole DIV element, can be changed easily to change zoom level of whole document if required.

Comment: ya i need a possible solution on this for all the browsers

Comment: Poor Opera, I think you might have hurt its feelings - I can see it crying in the corner ;-)

Comment: @Andy - well, can't enjoy *all* worlds... supporting the three major browsers is my current goal in life. :D

Comment: Hi i tried your solution it seems to be working for every browser but not working in IE 7,8 , Does there is any sols for this , Please its urgent

Comment: @user329539 sorry, not going to install Opera now - supporting the three major browsers is the most I can do ATM. It's possible to hide the buttons if the browser is not one of these to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

can i contribute please.
adding on Shadow Wizard code:

http://jsfiddle.net/GaPYe/

```
var _zoomLevel = 100;
function ChangeZoomLevel(diff) {
    _zoomLevel += diff;
    var oDiv = document.getElementById("Contents");
    if (typeof oDiv.style.MozTransform == "string")
        oDiv.style.MozTransform = "scale(" + (_zoomLevel / 100) + ")";
    else if (typeof oDiv.style.zoom == "string")
        oDiv.style.zoom = _zoomLevel  + "%";
        else if (typeof oDiv.style.OTransform == "string")
        oDiv.style.OTransform = "scale(" + (_zoomLevel / 100) + ")";
            else if (typeof oDiv.style.WebkitTransform == "string")
        oDiv.style.WebkitTransform = "scale(" + (_zoomLevel / 100) + ")";
                else if (typeof oDiv.style.MsTransform == "string")
        oDiv.style.MsTransform = "scale(" + (_zoomLevel / 100) + ")";
                    else if (typeof oDiv.style.transform == "string")
        oDiv.style.transform = "scale(" + (_zoomLevel / 100) + ")";
}
```

i think it works in all browsers now.