# How to resize browser window to 75% after site

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, resize

I want that when my page load then  browser window shrinks to 75% like we do with `Ctrl +/-` tabs

How can i do that with jquery?

Comment: The window or the content? You can't change the users browser window size.

Comment: I don't recommend it, but see [“Zoom” a browser window/view with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798331/zoom-a-browser-window-view-with-javascript) It might help to tell us why you want to do this; are you trying to solve another problem by zooming out?

Answer (score 0):

You cant achieve this. Zooming should be controlled by the user only. In addition, Each browser ressponds in its own way to zooming. Kindly read this:[Changing the browser zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055336/changing-the-browser-zoom-level)