# Auto scaling entire website to a % using zoom or other

Tags: html

purelocal dot com dot au
currently it zooms at 88% using the :
body id zoom2
class zoom1

however im wondering if there's a better way to do this.
removing above and applying zoom:0.88 to  seems to work.

basically : what is the best way to auto scale site to 0.88 for all browsers (without exceses footer padding). thankyou kindly!

Comment: http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798331/zoom-a-browser-window-view-with-javascript