# Simulate ctrl+/- by code

Tags: javascript, css

When you surf with your browser, you can increase or decrease the font dimension by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>.

Is there a way to **simulate** this operation by code (like javascript)?

I have to put a couple of button on my site to increase or decrease the size but to make it, I have to change dynamically a lot of font-size properties (BODY, INPUT, OPTIONS etc...)

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: What have you tried? you're not the first guy needed to change the font size in his site you know... Did you search for an answer first?

Comment: possible duplicate of [triggering browser Zoom-in and Zoom-out funtions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539955/triggering-browser-zoom-in-and-zoom-out-funtions)

Comment: @KooiInc I prefer this: http://whathaveyoutried.com redirects to the same thing.. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do this. Browser zoom is a feature that:

- may or may not be present in a browser,
- is implemented in different ways through browsers,
- only exists as a last-resort plumbing for bad websites.

---

> a couple of button on my site to increase or decrease the size but to make it, I have to change dinamically a lot of font-size properties

**What you *really* want to do is:**

- Scale your fonts in relative units (like `em` or `%`) everywhere,
- Change `document.body.style.fontSize` to modify your base size (which other elements will 
  use as their base size).

Specify the `body`'s font size in relative units too - In this way you can also respect the user's system settings (which every decent website should do).

There's plenty of resources on CSS font scaling around. Here's one:

http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Comment: There is also a solution called "responsive design", which adapts to the cbrowsers better than just using relative units.

Comment: AFAIK "responsive design" is about having (mainly) the layout adapt to the device (w/r/t the screen size, etc). These two sure can be used togehter