# How can i simulate browser events using javascript

Tags: javascript, browser

I want to simuate the zoom In and zoom out events of browser using javascript. Like in MAC you use `Command +` to zoom and in Windows `Control +`. I want to show the same effect as these commands, so I thought of triggering these using vanilla javascript. But not able to achieve anything till now. Has anyone implemented it?

To simulate the event, I am creating the event of keydown with Command and = (zoomIn in case of Mac), but it is not triggering the zoom event :-

```
let e = new Event("keydown", {"bubbles": true, "cancelable": true});
  e.key = "=";    // just enter the char you want to send 
  e.keyCode = 187;
  e.which = e.keyCode;
  e.altKey = false;
  e.ctrlKey = false;
  e.shiftKey = false;
  e.metaKey = true;
  this.dispatchEvent(e);
```

To verify, I am listening for the zoom event, the manual browser zoom, and javascript zoom both are going inside the if statement.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 187 && e.metaKey) {
    console.log('this is getting triggered');
    //debugger;
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, but in the case it is, don't mess with users' settings.

Comment: can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: @anurupr edited the question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19164758/839456 .   You can change the zoom of the page manually by setting the `zoom` property, not by triggering the zoom key combo

Answer (score 0):

You can try to emulate that behavior with [CSS property transform: scale()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#test {
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
</style>
<script>
  //TODO: Increase scale value by x each time you press button
  function zoomIn () {
    document.getElementById("test").style.transform = "scale(1.5)";
  }
  
  function zoomOut () {
    document.getElementById("test").style.transform = "scale(0.5)";
  }
</script>
<head>
<div id="test">
  <p>Test</p>
  <button onclick="zoomIn()">Zoom IN</button>
  <button onclick="zoomOut()">Zoom OUT</button>
</div>
<html>
```