# How can I implement a zoom function like the browser's CTRL +

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-6

I want a button that zoom in (increase font size is the main objective but images and tables etc is also wanted)

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this on your own site? or one you are visiting?

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386760/calling-keyevent-from-mouse/4386873#4386873) on some other question, it might be useful for you too

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Surely your users can just use their browser?

Comment: Your users' browser already has a zoom feature, as you've identified. No need to reinvent it.

Comment: Is this tagged IE6 because you really need an IE6 solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the [zoom css3 property](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/zoom) which does exactly this, the latest webkit browsers (chrome, safari) support it.

***edit**: apparently even IE6 supports it in some way, check comments below*

setting the zoom css property on your body or container should to the trick. Could be as simple as `$('body').css('zoom', '200%');` with jQuery.

Check http://jsfiddle.net/Ks6Yn/1/ for an example

Comment: I dont think IE6 supports css3

Comment: @user521180: If you explicitly need IE6 support i'm afraid you are out of luck on this feature unless you can fiddle some with relative fontsizing, it's much harder tho and probably won't work as expected.

Comment: oddly enough in this case, IE does support zoom... it was one of their hacks from years ago. but it behaves oddly... scales everything including form control borders...

Comment: @scunliffe: isn't that how zoom should work, zooming in on all components, including form controls and their borders?? Zoom <> scale imo :)

Comment: wow that is a miracle. it'll try to get it working and get back to you thanks

Comment: updated fiddle with form controls - notice the dropdown options in IE do not scale. http://jsfiddle.net/Ks6Yn/5/

Comment: @ChrisR - I was too late to edit my comment :-(  What I meant to say was that yes, it scales everything... (but even in IE this behavior has changed).  The select drop down is the oddest one, but at one time (doesn't appear to be happening now) IE scaled the borders of the elements too, which if you scale up say 10x makes massive borders on elements that look rediculous - since it is really the content (text font, and button parts) that you want scaled up. But I digress - as apparently they've changed this now.

Comment: Yeah if I look at an IE6/IE7 version of http://jsfiddle.net/Ks6Yn/6/ (revised version with high zoom factor) the borders on form elements look horrible (and the option issue is still there) However the rendering in Chrome looks nice.  I would argue that in Chrome/WebKit that the checkboxes should also scale up, but they don't.  I still think the best bet is to let the user use CTRL+[+] or CTRL+[Wheel] - and if they don't have a browser that supports zooming - upgrade!

Answer (score 2):

Following code zoomes the page to fit it to 1024px = 100% if available space is smaller. If there is enough space, the page is shown as is.

https://jsfiddle.net/xgqw5bjo/3/

Note, that the version with [setting style via jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/xgqw5bjo/2/) doesn't work as jQuery handles prefixes itself, but in this solution I need to control every one of them.

```js
~function () {
  var $window = $(window), $body = $("body");
  var ie = document.documentMode;
  
  function updateSizes() {
    var width = $window.width(), scale = Math.min(width / 1024, 1);

    var style = $body[0].style;
    
    style.msZoom = ie === 8 || ie === 9 ? scale : 1;
    style.zoom = ie === 10 || ie === 11 ? 1 : scale;
    style.mozTransform = "scale(" + scale + ")";
    style.oTransform = "scale(" + scale + ")";
    style.transform = "scale(" + scale + ")";
  }

  $window.resize(updateSizes);
  updateSizes();
}();
```

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  transform-origin: top left;
}

@supports (transform: scale(1)) {
  body {
    -ms-zoom: 1 !important;
    zoom: 1 !important;
  }
}

div {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 128px;
  background: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/eMSCb.png) repeat-x;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, blue, red 256px);
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Theoretically it should work in the following way:

- IE 5.5 - 7 <kbd>zoom</kbd>
- IE 8 - 9 <kbd>-ms-zoom</kbd>
- IE 10 - 11 <kbd>transform</kbd> & <kbd>ie</kbd>
- Edge 12+ <kbd>transform</kbd> & <kbd>@supports</kbd>
- Opera 11.5 - 12.0 <kbd>-o-transform</kbd>
- Opera 12.1 <kbd>transform</kbd>
- Firefox 3.5 - 15 <kbd>-moz-transform</kbd>
- Firefox 16+ <kbd>transform</kbd>
- Firefox 22+ <kbd>transform</kbd> (has `@supports`, but hasn't `zoom`)
- Safari 4 - 8 <kbd>zoom</kbd>
- Safari 9+ <kbd>transform</kbd> & <kbd>@supports</kbd> (appeared at the same time)
- Chrome 4 - 27 <kbd>zoom</kbd>
- Chrome 28 - 35 <kbd>zoom</kbd> (has `@supports`, but hasn't `transform` yet)
- Chrome 36+ <kbd>transform</kbd> & <kbd>@supports</kbd>

If I add `-webkit-transform`, it start work in Safari 3.1 - 3.2, but will brake a lot of others.

Actually for modern browsers result is made by using `transform` and disgarding `zoom`. All modern alive browsers (Edge, Firefox, Safari, Chrome) are already having <kbd>transform</kbd> & <kbd>@supports</kbd> and conform to standards, so the code won't be broken in future.

Tested the code in:

- IE 11
- Edge 15
- Opera 12.18
- Firefox 50
- Safari 5 (Win)
- Safari 10 (Mac)
- Chrome 54, 58

Details about browsers support:

- http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-zoom
- http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-featurequeries (about `@supports`)
- http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

---

<sup>[Translation of my answer on ruSO.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594479/178988)</sup>

Comment: Upvoted. Not because I used it, but because this is a solid answer. Complete with explanations, code samples, links, and browser support info. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

A working concept is to use JavaScript/jQuery to load a overwriting CSS style on click eg. a style with increased sizes of everything to overwrite the base one.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1**

You need to set a variable storing your zoom amount.

When you apply a zoom-in or zoom-out, change this variable accordingly and change the size of each element on your page, both width and height for elements displayed as block, and font size.

**Approach 2**

Have different stylesheet, load the needed one at the moment the zoom value change.

**Approach 3**

Change only the class relative to the zoom-level to the elements and have a CSS rule for each class of zoom.

Anyway, what you are trying to do looks wrong to me.